Can I change binding destination naming rule?
I want to change binding destination name separator. For example, given stream name is "inflow" and application name is "parsing",
I want to change inflow.parsing to inflow-parsing.
Can I do it?

Those names are generated by Spring Cloud Data Flow when it creates a stream and there are no provision for a custom separator.
You can override the application property app.XYZ.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination and/or app.ABC.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination when deploying the application.
You will have to choose your custom names for the queues and then use as the output for a source and an input for the processor etc.
